# Odoo error in the form xml

Tags: xml

I work on Odoo, I want to create a module, installation is ok but when I wan to upgrade with a xml file, I have some errors.
Here xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record id="cym_form" model="ir.ui.view"> 
<field name="name">Import Bank Statements</field>
<field name="model">account.bank.statement.import</field>
<field name="priority">1</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
                        <field name="cym_tag"/>
            <field name="modules" widget="one2many_tag"/>
</field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

And here error:

```
ParseError: "Wrong value for ir.ui.view.type: 'data'" while parsing 
/home/production/odoo/addons/crm_cym/form_cym_view.xml:4, near
<record id="cym_form" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">CYM Tag</field>
      <field name="module">cym.tag</field>
      <field name="priority">1</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <data><field name="cym_tag"/>
    <field name="modules" widget="one2many_tag"/>
      </data></field>
    </record>
```

If you have any ideas, I will be very grateful ! 
Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fields should be inside a `form` tag.

```
<form>
    <field name="cym_tag"/>
    <field name="modules" widget="one2many_tag"/>
</form>
```

Comment: This solution Also worked for me when I was using Inheritance. I needed to add the element I was inheriting before it worked. However, I was reading a book which didn't do that.